# What is the fastest way to perform a HTTP request and check for 404?

Tags: bash, apache, http, request, wget

Recently I needed to check for a huge list of filenames if they exist on a server. I did this by running a `for` loop which tried to `wget` each of those files. That was efficient enough, but took about 30 minutes in this case. I wonder if there is a faster way to check whether a file exists or not (since wget is for downloading files and not performing thousands of requests).
I don't know if that information is relevant, but it's an Apache server.

Comment: This should help: http://superuser.com/questions/197009/wget-head-request, especially [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/797372/15774)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Curl would be the best option in a for loop and here is a straight forward simple way, run this in your forloop

```
curl -I --silent http://www.yoururl/linktodetect | grep -m 1 -c 404
```

What this simply does is check the http response header for a 404 returned on the link and if its detected as a missing file/link throwing a 404 then the command line output will display you a number 1; otherwise, if the file/link is valid and does not return a 404 then the command line output will display you a number 0.